# Keep select item into a variable

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have this code to write my select option, but if I want to keep the selection into a variable and use it in the same page in my PHP code what must I do?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div { color:red; }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="garden" multiple="multiple">
<option>Flowers</option>
<option selected="selected">Shrubs</option>
<option>Trees</option>
<option selected="selected">Bushes</option>
<option>Grass</option>
<option>Dirt</option>
 </select>
<div></div>
<script>
$("select").change(function () {
var str = "";
$("select option:selected").each(function () {
str += $(this).text() + " ";
});
$("div").text(str);
})
.trigger('change');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean to store that variable for later use? you could use a database, local storage, session storage, cookies, php sessions, text files...

Comment: Whack it in a cookie within the JS - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie

Comment: It's just that I whould like to use as much as it's possible php because javascript and those kind of things are over my power a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a hidden field :

```
<input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" />
```

Store the selected value in this in onchange function:

```
$('#Hidden1').val($("select option:selected").val());
```

Later you can access this value with:  `$('#Hidden1').val()`

Answer (score 0):

PHP will not access changes done by javascript until you send request again to php through normal GET/POST/Ajax. For Form GET or Ajax you can use either hidden field or js global variable where you should store the selected value. For Form POST, you should go for hidden field.